# Проблема с авторизацией (vk api, python vklancer)

Tags: ubuntu, vkontakte-api, python-3.x

На моем ПК (python 3.4, ubuntu 15.10) бот нормально работает (т.е как задумано: отправляет сообщения и т.д. абсолютно без ошибок)

Арендовал VPS, поставил туда ubuntu-14.04-x86-minimal, поставил pip3 через aptitude, установил vklancer (тоже без ошибок). 
Далее начинается цирк, а именно:

```
root@istrueorfalse:/home/finder/bot# python3 main.py 
Инициализация
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot_modules.wait_command()
  File "/home/finder/bot/bot_modules.py", line 73, in wait_command
    lstmsg = last_msg()
  File "/home/finder/bot/bot_modules.py", line 110, in last_msg
    return vk.messages.getHistory(count=1, peer_id=chat_id2)["response"]["items"][0]
KeyError: 'response'
```

(1 это для отладки). Далее убираю try except и респонс от вк приобретает такой вид:

```
In [11]: vk.messages.send(user_id=158986242, message="test")
Out[11]: 
{'error': {'error_code': 5,
  'error_msg': 'User authorization failed: no access_token passed.',
  'request_params': [{'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'},
   {'key': 'method', 'value': 'messages.send'},
   {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.42'},
   {'key': 'message', 'value': 'test'},
   {'key': 'user_id', 'value': '158986242'}]}}
```

Повторюсь, код одинаковый на двух машинах. Версия Python - тоже. Везде запускаю через 3ю версию. Версия модуля - тоже одинаковая.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в каком направлении думать дальше.

Comment: Что-то с `access_token`. Может быть вообще не передан. А если передан, возможно не валидный, а если валидный, то попробуйте выполнить запрос к API с параметром v=3.0. Ещё как вариант, страна аккаунта и сервера разные.

Comment: Действительно, сервер находится в Италии, а аккаунт России.
Последняя активность в вк (настройки), говорят о том, что авторизация валидна, Не подскажете, что можно сделать в случае, если Ваше последнее предположение верное ?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала к запросу ВК на отправку сообщения добавить параметр v=3.0

Comment: проблема не решилась, ошибка та же.

Comment: в общем, код сводится к такому:

from vklancer import api
from vklancer import utils
access_token = utils.oauth('login', 'pass')
vk = api.API(token=access_token)
vk.messages.send(user_id=int_param, message="test")

Comment: Но я не вижу, что Вы передаете access_token. Где он?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35930/discussion-between-alex-dless-and-modal).

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает, если не передан `access_token`. Попробуйте выполнить запрос с браузера, перейдя по ссылке `https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=158986242&message=test&access_token=ВАШ ТОКЕН`